# Is it medically advisable to have spectacle lenses perfectly aligned with each other?

Tags: eye, ophthalmology, optometry, vision, lenses

I have noticed some local brands of spectacles having the lenses slightly angled as shown in the second image below ("If lenses are at an angle"). I believe it is done to have the lenses blend in along with the curved contour of the face.
**From a medical perspective, shouldn't the lenses be perfectly aligned with each other** as shown in the first image ("Normal myopia correction")?
Even in the case of binoculars, people complain of "headache" when lenses are not properly aligned (https://www.birdwatching.com/optics/education/alignment.html).
Wouldn't lenses positioned at an angle, cause the extraocular and intraocular muscles to have to strain more, in order to bring the visual into focus? Thereby causing more strain?

[image]

Here are some examples:
Specs 1 (plastic lens), top:
[image]
Specs 1, bottom:
[image]
Specs 1, side: (is it ok for the lens to be slanted like a forward-slash? Won't it shift the point of convergence?)
[image]
Specs 2 (glass lens), top:
[image]
Specs 2, bottom:
[image]
Specs 2, side: (lens is slanted here too)
[image]
Specs 3 (plastic lens), top:
[image]
Specs 4 (glass lens), side: (note how the lenses are not vertically aligned with each other)
[image]

Comment: If the glasses were manufactured like that, then isn't it possible the lenses have been ground to account for it?

Comment: Can such adjustment be done for plastic lenses too? Assuming the local brands actually care to do so. I've updated the question with photos of some spectacles I purchased over the years. Do note the way some lenses jut out of the frame contour at weird angles and the lack of alignment vertically and horizontally.

Comment: I would imagine plastic lenses can be made to conform to any specifications they want.

Comment: Ok, but from the images shown, does it look like care has been taken to ensure proper focus and to account for the angle? Is it a known fact or an accepted standard in optometry, that all spectacles manufacturers follow responsible practices and measurements per user to ensure that light rays are brought to the right focal point? I've been to quite a few places where they don't even measure the distance between the eyes.

Comment: I can't tell what the specs of a lens are by just looking at it.